# Roblox PONG Collision And Direction Not Working

Tags: lua, roblox, 2d-games, pong

I'm making a PONG game in Roblox, but it seems the ball keeps going to The bottom left, and sometimes the bottom right of the screen, the problem with this - is that its supposed to fly left or right, and the collision with the bars and the ball doesn't work, and all this is running in a frame, but even the frame doesn't have collision with the ball.

```
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")

local ball = script.Parent.ball
local frame1 = script.Parent.Frame1
local frame2 = script.Parent.Frame2

local initialDirection = math.random(0, 1) == 0 and -0.01 or 0.01
local ballSpeed = Vector2.new(initialDirection, 0.01)

local function moveFrames(direction)
    local newPosition
    if direction == "up" then
        newPosition = UDim2.new(0, 0, -0.1, 0)
    elseif direction == "down" then
        newPosition = UDim2.new(0, 0, 0.1, 0)
    end

    if frame1.Position.Y.Scale + newPosition.Y.Scale >= 0 and frame1.Position.Y.Scale + newPosition.Y.Scale + frame1.Size.Y.Scale <= 1 then
        frame1.Position = frame1.Position + newPosition
    end

    if frame2.Position.Y.Scale + newPosition.Y.Scale >= 0 and frame2.Position.Y.Scale + newPosition.Y.Scale + frame2.Size.Y.Scale <= 1 then
        frame2.Position = frame2.Position + newPosition
    end
end

local function onInputBegan(input, gameProcessed)
    if gameProcessed then return end

    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.W then
        moveFrames("up")
    elseif input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.S then
        moveFrames("down")
    end
end

local function updateBallPosition()
    ball.Position = ball.Position + UDim2.new(ballSpeed.X, 0, ballSpeed.Y, 0)
end

local function checkBallCollision()
    if ball.Position.Y.Scale <= 0 or ball.Position.Y.Scale + ball.Size.Y.Scale >= 1 then
        ballSpeed = Vector2.new(ballSpeed.X, -ballSpeed.Y)
    end

    if ball.Position.X.Scale <= frame1.Position.X.Scale + frame1.Size.X.Scale and
        ball.Position.Y.Scale + ball.Size.Y.Scale >= frame1.Position.Y.Scale and
        ball.Position.Y.Scale <= frame1.Position.Y.Scale + frame1.Size.Y.Scale then
        ballSpeed = Vector2.new(-ballSpeed.X, ballSpeed.Y)
    end

    if ball.Position.X.Scale + ball.Size.X.Scale >= frame2.Position.X.Scale and
        ball.Position.Y.Scale + ball.Size.Y.Scale >= frame2.Position.Y.Scale and
        ball.Position.Y.Scale <= frame2.Position.Y.Scale + frame2.Size.Y.Scale then
        ballSpeed = Vector2.new(-ballSpeed.X, ballSpeed.Y)
    end
end

local function pongGameLoop()
    while true do
        checkBallCollision()
        updateBallPosition()
        wait(0.03)
    end
end

UserInputService.InputBegan:Connect(onInputBegan)
pongGameLoop()
```

Nothing really worked, maybe someone can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ball goes to bottom left or bottom right:** it happens because in your `ballSpeed` variable, speed by Y axis is `0.01`, so to make ball fly left or right: you need to change Y axis to `0`:

`local ballSpeed = Vector2.new(initialDirection, 0)`

**Collision with the bars and the ball doesn't work:**
it works fine for me. I think that it does't work for you, because you made size of `Frame1`, `Frame2` and `ball` by `Offset`. If you do, change size of these objects to `Scale` or change your code.

You can also see game where I tested your code (it expires in 7 days): https://fex.net/s/a5bpt5d